# passing array of object to member function in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object

I am beginner in oop in c++ fairly say in programming. i am trying to make the array of objects and pass it to member function sort(class_name[size]) to sort by their id number.
i have tried so hard for passing arrays of objects but cant find the solution.
please help on it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Second, is the sort function part of some exercise? If not, use `std::sort(the_array, the_array + the_array_length);`.

Comment: Use more intuitive class as `std::vector` or `std::array`. C-array syntax is ugly.

Comment: Don't pass arrays, use `std::vector`.  Your issue is one that `std::vector` was meant to resovle.

Comment: @shrijantripathi Pasting code walls in comments is *not* the correct thing to do. It belongs in your question, properly formatted and in a form that allows copy/paste + compile + run = problem state.

Comment: is it not possible to call the member function like  for(int i=0;i<n;i++) s.sort(class_name[],n);

Comment: @WhozCraig  sorry for that , i am new here

Comment: @shrijantripathi no worries, but spend time [**reading these**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) before asking. Consider it self-preservation, as following those guidelines will *radically* reduce the baptism-by-fire core temperature.

Answer (score 1):

Classically and erroneously, arrays have been passed by:

1. Name of the array
2. Address of first element

The biggest issue is the length (capacity) of the array.  In C and C++ the array (not std::array), does not store it's capacity.  So the receiving function has no clue to the end of the array.

Another issue is the number of elements in the array.  In C and C++, the array structure does not maintain the number of items in the array.  An array may have a capacity of 32 elements, but only 3 loaded.

If you write your own functions and use an array, please provide arguments for the array, the capacity and the number of elements in the array.

**Edit 1:**
One problem with passing a pointer or the address of the first element is that the pointer only points to a single character, and technically, not an array object.  The assumption has been that an array is a container where the elements are consecutive with no other data types between.  Thus you only needed to know the first position of the array.

A problem is that I could pass a pointer to a single character and the receiving function would treat the data as an array of characters instead of a single character.  Thus creating undefined behavior often known as buffer overruns.

So to be more type safe, you should use the array syntax when passing arrays rather than a pointer to the first element.  For better safety, using `std::vector` or `std::array` or put the array in a structure and pass the structure.

Comment: The array's size is stored in the type. It is possible to keep that information, both in C and C++.